# How to increase the font size of method trace view in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, I captured a [Method Trace](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-methodtrace.html#trace) use [CPU Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-cpu.html#running), but on my computer (screen size is 1920*1080), the font of the method name in Trace View is so small that I can't see it clearly.

So I want to know any one has the solution to change the size of trace view.

The method trace looks like the following figure:
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out they just hardcoded font size to 8. So there is only a very weird solution with patching Android Studio jar files.

Steps:

1. Find `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/sdk-tools.jar`
2. Copy it somewhere else(do not forget to make a backup in case something goes wrong).
3. Unzip it and pick `com/android/tools/perflib/vmtrace/viz/CallHierarchyRenderer.class`
4. Take any hex editor and replace byte sequence `0504 4100` with `0504 4180`
   (actually, you replace 8 in class constant pool with 24)
5. Pack modified class back `jar uf sdk-tools.jar com/android/tools/perflib/vmtrace/viz/CallHierarchyRenderer.class`
6. Copy patched sdk-tools.jar back to its original location

**Before**
[image: Before]

**After**
[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one as an alternative to see flame graph of .trace file, it is pretty similar with call chart.

https://aflame.rhye.org

However, if you want to see call chart, you can modify source code on this repo by adding this command on the source code.

```html
--inverted
```

https://github.com/rschlaikjer/erlang-atrace-flamegraphs

Answer (score -1):

You can use this alternative android methods profiler/trace-viewer : https://github.com/Grigory-Rylov/android-methods-profiler

- it can resize font by 'ctrl' + '+'/'-'
- allows you add custom methods highlighting
- allows you to add custom bookmarks
- works much more faster than Android Studio profiler
- can easily record traces from the start, which is not always possible for another AS Profiler
- can open big trace files (400 Mb+)

[Call trace with bookmarks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXBFE.jpg) [Threads list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcd9y.jpg)